# Using "the" before dates

Tags: definite-article

English learners are taught not to write "the" when writing dates but I see that many native speakers do. Or am I wrong? The sentence below was written by a native speaker.
"I paid off my PayPal Credit balance on the 10th September."

Comment: We would write 'on the tenth of September', but it's not usual to write the article when the day is given in figures.

Comment: "The" before dates is acceptable if you use the format **the** [ordinal number] **of** [month name as a word] example: _the tenth (or 10th) of September_. Writing 'my birthday is the 10 September' or ' I came here on the 10/09/2020' would be unusual and probably seen as an error.

Comment: Then this sentence I was asking about is wrong. It should be "I paid off my PayPal credit balance on the tenth of September." Right?

Comment: "On the tenth of September" would be technically correct, but we would rarely write out the ordinal as a full word.  So really it should be "on 10th September" (or "on 10 September").  The native speaker simply didn't follow standard practice in this case.

Comment: I would definitely write the ordinal as a word in direct speech, e.g. _"I am seeing my lawyer on the third of October" said Julian._

Comment: @MichaelHarvey On reflection I agree with you there.

Comment: I believe I would do with cardinals, too. I think it is a style choice, but I really hate things like _"I spent 5 years in jail", said my mother_. Would I write _"Grandfather collapsed so I dialled nine-nine-nine" said Peter_? I think so.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a native speaker, I was taught the same as you - that the words "the" and "of" are pronounced, but not spelt out.  So I would write:

> On 10th September

(Traditionally, the "th" is written in superscript - 10<sup>th</sup>.  With the decline of handwritten correspondence and the rise of print, this practice nearly disappeared for a while, but has returned now that many word processors will do it automatically for you.  It is nevertheless optional.)

It is equally acceptable to write:

> On 10 September

Both are pronounced "on the tenth of September".

This is standard practice (to omit the "the" in writing), but that doesn't mean that all native speakers will follow it.  In formal usage, "the" can be reinserted, but "of" must be as well:

> The more complicated the style of date, the more formal it is... The *and* *of* are optional, but if you do use them you must add both *the* and *of*; it would be incorrect to say only *13th of April* or *the 13th April*. ([English Lessons Brighton)](https://englishlessonsbrighton.co.uk/how-to-write-dates-british-american-english/))

If I were writing out the date in full (as words rather than with figures), I would write:

> On the tenth of September

but we rarely do that.  It might be appropriate in a legal document.  I also agree with Michael Harvey that it would be better to use the full version in direct speech:

> "I'm seeing him on the third of October," she said.

The full version would also be common when referring to certain holidays or festivities (in which case the ordinal number would probably be capitalised too):

> On the Fifth of November

> On the Fourth of July

I would also include the "the" if I were omitting the month:

> I was there on the 10th.

(This is another place where "tenth" would work well.)

Much of the above is primarily applicable to British English.  In American English, except in very formal contexts or when referring to the Fourth of July, they write dates the other way round - as "September 10th" or "September 10" (although nowadays including the ordinal suffix is apparently rare in the US).  British people sometimes do this as well, although some Brits regard it as an American practice to be avoided.  Here the word "the" is not written, either, but is still pronounced - at least in Britain; I have observed that Americans often say "September tenth" without pronouncing "the".

Comment: Thank you both for your detailed explanation. I think I didn't understand Michael Harvey's explanation.  ("The" before dates is acceptable if you use the format the [ordinal number] of [month name as a word] example: the tenth (or 10th) of September. Writing 'my birthday is the 10 September' or ' I came here on the 10/09/2020' would be unusual and probably seen as an error. – Michael Harvey 2 hours ago  ) I understand it to mean   "The' is acceptable if I write in words "the tenth of September" and "the 10th of September" . I am not talking about pronunciation. Am I right?

Comment: He is only talking about how you write it. It is possible to include the "the" if you also include the "of".  (Both of them are included when speaking it out, regardless.)  But it is much more common to miss out both the "the" and "of" in writing.  There are some circumstances where it may be included, as I set out. But if you put "The 10th of March" at the top of your letter, that would look strange, and if you wrote "Thank you for your letter of the 10th of March", that would look at least somewhat odd. It is very much the preferred practice to miss out the "the" and "of" in most situations.

Comment: In speech, both words are always spoken (except of course when the format is reversed - "March 10th" doesn't have an "of").

Comment: Oh, I see. I will rephrase to make sure I don't misunderstand. Thus, it can be written as "the tenth of September" which is formal/rare. Or "The 10th of September" which is not usual because "the" is not used when the day is given in numbers as Kate Bunting said. You said native speakers may omit "the" in writing. Do you mean for example here "The 10th of September"? Sorry, for annoying you but it's not easy.

Comment: No problem.  "The tenth of September" is formal/literary/rare, and "the 10th of September" is probably rarer.  We usually write "10th September" or "10 September".  Is that any clearer?

Comment: Oh, yes!!! Thank you. I must say most people on different forums give up after the second question. Thank you. I appreciate your help. One last question. If I add "on".  "I was born on the tenth of September" again formal/literary/rare. "I was born on the 10th of September" rarer. "I was born on 10th September" or "10 September" are usual. Right? In my language we don't have so many different forms.

Comment: You're correct.  They are all just different ways of writing it.  Informally, you could also write "I was born on 10/9" (although that can also be pronounced as "the tenth of the ninth") - but that would confuse American readers, who would think it meant 9th October.

Comment: Thanks a million!!! I usually copy and paste everything into my notes will do later.  If I have a question , but I don't think I will because  eveything is clear now, but in case I have,  may I ask you again?

Comment: @AntoniaA Of course.

Comment: That's very kind of you.

Comment: Hello, @rjpond. I was reading this thread again.  I read in the article above that "the" and "of" if they are used they should be used together. In writing.  As in "The 13th of April" not "The 13th April."  But does it only happen when we announce the date? In my original example written by a native speaker there is "the" and no "of". "On the 10th September."  This is the only question I have. I also read the article everything is clear to me. Thanks for sharing.

Comment: Hello @AntoniaA It isn't just when announcing the date.  Even though the native speaker wrote "On the 10th September", they would probably still pronounce it as "on the tenth of September".  "Of" would most likely be unstressed, so would become /əv/ or maybe even /ə/ (in rapid speech) rather than the stressed form /ɒv/, but I would be surprised if "of" were omitted altogether.

Comment: Yes, I understand that. But why  didn't he include "of" in writing? If we should use both "of" and "the" not only one of them as it's written in the article.

Comment: Ah, I see.  I don't know.  Either he wasn't taught the same rule or he made a mistake.  I suspect you are right that if he was writing the date outside of a sentence - for example, at the top of the letter - he wouldn't have written the word "the".  (This isn't a distinction that I was taught and it wasn't one that was recommended by the articles I consulted when writing my answer.)

Comment: I see. Thank you!!!!